# gcloud kubectl failing to connect to Kubernetes API Endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've setup a cluster in Google Container Engine and according to the Console, the API Endpoint for it seems to be completely different than the public APIs of either master or nodes in the cluster (which I thought was weird).

When trying the `gcloud` command line tool to manage the cluster, all commands issued with `cloud preview container kubectl` fail with a timeout reaching the API Endpoint.

I've tried changing Network Firewall rules and nothing seems to work.

I was trying to follow the [guestbook](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/guestbook) tutorial to deploy my Docker instances in the Kubernetes managed GKE cluster and am currently stuck on not being able to issue any commands against the cluster.

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: Given the IPs assigned by default to the nodes are ephemeral, I'm wondering if they could have changed and the metadata of the cluster wasn't updated with it... It's possible that the IP currently showing was the one assigned to the master node when the cluster was created and now that I'm trying to use it after having created it a while ago, it's a different IP. I couldn't find a way to update the cluster definition with the new IP so wondering if the only option at this point is recreating the cluster and redeploying?

Comment: It's quite unexpected that the master VM would have changed IPs, but maybe that is what happened? I'd love to be able to investigate further, and have responded to your identical question [on the google-containers mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-containers/3Oaqkan9Ux8/7t72e76FyDUJ).

Answer (score 1):

As per [our discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-containers/3Oaqkan9Ux8/discussion) on the google-containers mailing list, this was caused by the VMs' IP addresses changing when they were stopped and then re-brought up a few weeks later. Container Engine currently doesn't handle cases like this where all the IP addresses in a cluster change, and unfortunately the best option at the moment is to delete the cluster and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, this helped:
`gcloud beta container get-credentials`